# Difficulty in creating program for admission in schools

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had just made a project program that functions as an easy way to apply for admission in school. So far, everything went kinda okay but I am not getting the proper output.

What I should be getting is that when student name is entered for admission the class(i.e, t2/t1) should be checked if there are available seats and suitably either enter the student or not. When we search for a student the student name as well as ID number must be displayed. When we delete a student, we must get the class list as well.

Please look into the material posted below and help me.

```
def search(t2):
   t2=(('xxx',1),('yyy',2),('zzz',3))
   s=input('Enter student ID=')
   for i in range(len(t2)):
       for ch in t2:
           if ch==s:
               print'Student =>',t2[i],'of Id number',t2[i+1]
               break
   else:
       print'Invalid Entry, try again'


def details(t1):
       n=raw_input('Enter applicant name=')
       t2=(('xxx',1),('yyy',2),('zzz',3))
       for i in range(len(t1)):
           if len(t1)<5:
               t2=t2+(n,i)
               break
           elif len(t1)==5:
               print'Sorry, class full'
           else:
               print'Sorry, class full'
       print'Student added successfully to class'
   def delete(t2):
       l=list(t2)
       j=input('Enter the student ID=')
       for i in range(len(t2)):
           for ch in l:
               if j==ch:
                   del l[i]
                   del l[i+1]
                   break
               else:
                   print'Student not found. Please try again'
       print tuple(l)
   n=input('Enter the number of students=')
   t1=tuple()
   t2=(('xxx',1),('yyy',2),('zzz',3)) 
   name=raw_input('Enter the student name=')
   idn=input('Enter the Id no.=')
   for i in range(n):
       t1=t1+(name,)
       t1=t1+(idn,)
   while True:
       print'\n\n\t\t----Admission Menu----'
       print'\t\t1->Apply for admission'
       print'\t\t2->Search for a student'
       print'\t\t3->Remove a student'
       print'\t\t4->Exit'

       ch=input('Enter your choice=')
       if ch==1:
           details(t1)
       elif ch==2:
           search(t1)
       elif ch==3:
           delete(t1)
       elif ch==4:
           print'Thank You for visiting --School Name--'
           exit()
       else:
           print'Wrong choice, please select a valid choice and try again'
```

Comment: add details about exact problem you are facing and the point out the code that may have caused the issue.

Comment: What I should be getting is that when student name is entered for admission the class(i.e, t2/t1) should be checked if there are available seats and suitably either enter the student or not. When we search for a student the student name as well as ID number must be displayed. When we delete a student, we must get the class list as well.

Comment: add these details in the problem description

Comment: And please show what you are getting instead of what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of problem where the usage of a database would help you really much. Tasks like insert, search, delete are standard for that. An easy and modern solution could be to use MongoDB with PyMongo (for python integration).

Otherwise, in the function search, you overwrite t2 directly at the beginning. I am not sure if this was intended, but if yes then I have no idea how that should work.